# C++ GLFloat arrays within an array

Tags: c++

Trying to create an array of type GLFloat which contains arrays of type GLFloat.

```
GLfloat p0[] = { -3, 0, -3};
GLfloat p1[] = {  3, 0, -3};

GLfloat points[2][3] = {p0, p1};
```

Error message: Type GLFloat cannot be used to an entity of type GLFloat

Answer (score 0):

You could create the matrix directly.

```
GLfloat points[2][3] = {{-3, 0, -3}, { 3, 0, -3}};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use braced initialisation the way to go would be

```
points[2][3] = { {-3, 0, -3}, {3, 0, -3} };
```

Why your way doesn't work:

```
points[2][3] = { p0, p1 };
```

What happens is that p0 decays to `float*`  and so does p1 which you cannot assign to `float`.

Another option would be with `memcpy`:

```
std::memcpy(&points[0], &p0, 3 * sizeof(float));
std::memcpy(&points[1], &p1, 3 * sizeof(float));
```

But I'm not a fan of all this address manipulation and `memcpy` when using C++